# hibernate error generating annotations

Tags: hibernate

i use mysql5

and i put the driver:
sun.jdbc.odbc.driver
when i run the hibernate code generation configuration it import table from database but with errors at annotations?
any help please

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up the ODBC bridge to MySQL?

If not, use `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` which is the [Type 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver#Type_4_Driver_-_Native-Protocol_Driver) driver for MySQL. You can download it from [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.16/mysql-connector-java-5.1.16.jar) and add to `CLASSPATH`.